# Free Google Forms alternative that works offline

Tags: windows, gratis, offline, survey, forms

I'm searching for a software that allows me to create a questionaire with a nice UI that I can fill and that then enters that data into a spreadsheet.

Google Forms fulfills this job well but I want a software that works offline on Windows.
If there an offline software that works like Google Forms and that is free?

Comment: Please [read this](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/48/how-to-ask-for-an-alternative-to-some-software) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

[Formotus](http://www.formotus.com/) may be a possible answer. Whilst it is not free, sorry, but there is a good solution with a free trial.

There is a pricing matrix available [here](http://www.formotus.com/product/pricing).

Formotus is optimized for offline data collection forms in mobile apps for iOS and Android as well as Windows. [Data can now be submitted to Google Sheets](http://www.formotus.com/20532/blog-news/business-forms-mobile-apps-google-drive-sheets) among other destinations, and has the following [features](http://www.formotus.com/product) listed:

> - Offline First
> - Rich data collection
> - Data connectors
> - 2 Ways to Create
> - InfoPath migration
> - Dispatch and workflow

Answer (score 1):

You can use Clappia (https://clappia.com)

You can create a form that can be accessed on the mobile by your users. This form is accessible offline as well. You just need to open your particular app inside Clappia once and they will be loaded even if there is no internet. They can submit data to this and the submitted data will be uploaded automatically whenever your users are connected to the internet.

Disclaimer: I am associated with Clappia

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as far as I know there is no free offline alternative to google forms.

We received similar requests from our clients (utility company managing technicians in remote areas with limited network, HVAC installers, etc.), so we decided to build a solution for this : Fieldeo (https://fieldeo.com/). Here how we made it :

- Easy to install on iOS, Android and even PCs/Mac
- Quick delivery, lower than 2 weeks (reuse of our backend architecture for each client)
- Input types of any type: we customize the fields in order to build great UX
- Pricing models based on your needs (fixed price or monthly ; unlimited users)
- Native Offline support
- Administration interface so the supervisor can validate the data before it gets exported
- Exports in multiple formats

Feel free to reach out if you want to know more and discuss the technical challenges behind that.